# Fast format conversion open source library

Tags: optimization, open-source, assembly, visual-c++, intrinsics

Can someone advise me open source format conversion library? Optimized for SSE, SSE2.

Formats for conversion: I420, YUY2, RGB(16-bit, 32-bit).

I found only VirtualDub Kasumi library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at FFmpeg's [libswscale library](http://git.ffmpeg.org/?p=libswscale;a=summary), which is licensed under the terms of the LGPL.

I'm not sure if libswscale will compile with MSVC (it probably won't), but you can always use MSYS/MingW to compile libswscale to a shared library and use that in your MSVC project.

Answer (score 0):

[libyuv](https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/) is an open source project that includes YUV scaling and conversion functionality.

Scale YUV to prepare content for compression, with point, bilinear or box filter.
Convert to YUV from webcam formats.
Convert from YUV to formats for rendering/effects.
Rotate by 90/180/270 degrees to adjust for mobile devices in portrait mode.

Optimized for SSE2/SSSE3/AVX2 on x86/x64.
Optimized for Neon on Arm.
Optimized for DSP R2 on Mips.